# How to print the correct time from the datetime input in the form

Tags: django

I am getting date and time input from form through datetimepicker in Django.
Because the current template outputs {{ form }} , you need to set the format of the time to be output to the template in models.py.

I entered 3 PM, but 06:00 is stored in the db, and the time obtained by the get_time function is also 06:00. What should I set to display 15:00 in the template?

```
def get_time(self):
    return self.date.strftime('%H:%M')

@property
def get_html_url(self):
    url = reverse('dataroom:training_edit', args=(self.id,))
    return f'<div class="training-title" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#training_{self.id}">{self.get_time()}: {self.topic}' \
           f'<a href="{url}" style="color:black;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">Edit</span></a></div>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set globally on what date time format you want in django template

in your settings.py add the following:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i'
```

To customize it, you can refer official [django date time documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) which specifies different date time format